# IE doesn't support file upload in a dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

If I explicitly write out a form in the HTML like this:

```
 <form action='upload_1-img.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
   <input type='file' id='image' name='image'><input type='submit'>
 </form>
```

then all goes as expected in IE.
But if I do the following, it works in Chrome and FF but not in IE8:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    imgform = document.createElement('form');
    imgform.id = 'imgform';
    imgform.method='post';
    imgform.enctype='multipart/form-data';
    imgform.action ='upload_1-img.php';
    $('body').append(imgform);
    $('#imgform').append("<input type='file' id='image' name='image' /><input type=submit>");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, if I use `var_dump($_FILES)` in `upload_1-img.php`, it returns an empty array. IE8 uploads a file normally when this same form is explicitly coded in HTML. But I need the file upload to work after the form is created dynamically in javascript. What's the workaround to make this work in IE8?

Comment: out of interest, why are you using `document.createElement` for the `form` element, when you're working with jQuery? Couldn't you just write the whole `<form>....</form>` block the way you've already got it for the `<input>` elements?

Comment: as SDC said, jquery would fix your problem. However, i suspect `imgform.enctype='multipart/form-data';` is actually your problem. Try using `imgform.setAttribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
var form=document.createElement("<form id='imgform' action='upload_1-img.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>");
$('body').append(form);
$('#imgform').append("<input type='file' id='image' name='image' /><input type=submit>");
```

Source: http://verens.com/2005/07/06/ie-bugs-dynamically-creating-form-elements/

If you check the bottom of the article, it states that

> The above code will mostly work in IE, except when you actually need to use the multipart  aspect of it (uploading a file, for example), when it will barf.
>
> In this case, IE seems to insist on the following crappy code:
>
> form=document.createElement('<form action="shoppingcart_xhr.php" method="POST" > enctype="multipart/form-data" target="shoppingcart_iframe">');

Comment: wonderful! except that now it crashes in FF and Chrome! I guess I just need to have browser-conditional code in this case?